# Probability of a salary increase or the maximum of n random draws

Tags: probability

I ask my boss for a raise and because he is a psychopath he says yes, but we need to play a game.

Every day, during $j$ days from $j=1:n$, I will be assigned a random number randomly using an unknown distribution with mean$=\log(n+1-j)$, $\max=\log(n+1-j) \times \log(n+1-j)$ and $\min=0$.

This is, on the first day, the number is drawn randomly between $[0,\ldots,\log^2(n)]$, and on the second day, I will be assigned a random number between $[0,\ldots, \log^2(n-1)]$, and so on until in the last day, I am assigned a number between $[0, \log^2(1)]$.

My boss will grant me an increase equal to the maximum number across the $n$ draws. Is there any meaningful way to bound or approximate what will be my salary increase?

I'm particularly interested in showing that the raise that I will get, i.e. the maximum over the $n$ draws is higher than $\log(n)$.

Edit: This problem doesn't come from a textbook, so I can't provide a source. $\log$ refers to the natural logarithm.

Comment: Your distribution is not clear.  On day $j=1$ the mean and the max are $0$ but the min is somehow greater than both.  And what base did you mean for the log, anyway?  Even if you meant $e$, for day $j=2$ we'd have max<mean< min.  Nor is it clear how all these numbers determine your raise...

Comment: I changed the min to 0.

Comment: Not enough. For day 1, you are saying contradictory thing. Is it $\log j$ or $\log (n-j+1)$? for the mean and max?

Comment: That really doesn't help much.

Comment: Please edit to include the source for this problem. Linking to the original might help supply the many missing details.

Comment: Edits made. There is no textbook reference I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Markov's inequality to find a lower bound on the probability that your salary increase is lower than some quantity $a$.

Let $X_j$ be the number on day $j$ and $Y = \max_j X_j$ be your salary increase. **I suppose that the $X_j$'s are independent** and $n \geqslant 2$.

Since $\mathbb{P}(X \geqslant a) \leqslant \frac{\log j}{a}$ for any $a > 0$ (Markov's inequality), using the independance of the $X_j$'s we have
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y < a) &= \prod_j \mathbb{P}(X_j < a) \\
&= \prod_j (1 - \mathbb{P}(X_j \geqslant a)) \\
\mathbb{P}(Y < a) &\geqslant \prod_j (1 - \frac{\log j}{a}) = \frac{1}{a^n} \prod_j (a - \log j).
\end{align*}$$
Note that you can discard $j = n$ since $X_n = 0$ will not change the value of $Y = \max_j X_j$. Hence, with $a = \log n$ we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y < \log n) \geqslant \frac{\log n}{\log n} \times \frac{\log \frac{n}{2}}{\log n} \times \ldots \times \frac{\log \frac{n}{n-1}}{\log n}
$$
which becomes very small as $n$ grows.